# What does "$" mean in R programming language

Tags: r

What does the "$" mean in the following line of code?

`db$Continent <- NA`

Comment: Have you tried `?"$"` ?

Comment: There's a good explanation of data structures such as dataframes here: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Data-structures.html#data-frames.

Answer (score -1):

Generally speaking, the `$` operator is used to extract or subset a specific part of a data object in R.

In your example, you're assigning `NA` to `Continent`, as @dario pointed out in the comments.

Comment: This answer is wrong. In the example OP is **not** looking for the Continent NA but **assigning** NA (missing value indicator) to the column/variable `Continent`

Comment: Yikes, just realized that. Thanks for pointing out. I'll edit that real quick